# Excel Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to get a hyperlink 'jump to' cell to change based off of the cell contents of another page. Currently I have,

**=IF(C46="S",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#"&C5,"!A1"),"*"),IF(C46="A",HYPERLINK("#Encounter!A1","@")))**

the first part of the function is wonderful, the second part works great as well but not for what I want.

I have 3 sheets in the scenario "**Players**","**Encounter**", and "**m1**"
 I currently have my "**Encounter**" sheet set up so the cells reference the cells in "**Players**", and "**m1**" sheet reference the cells in "**Encounter**".  I then sort the "**Encounter**" sheet which in turn sorts "**m1**". The hyperlink is on "**m1**" and I want the 'jump to' cell, A1, currently in the hyperlink, to dynamically change to the cell next to a cell in "**Encounter**" that contains the value of the primary cell on "**Players**". so, if after I sort the value in B1 drops to B6, the 'jump to' cell in the hyperlink will follow from A1 to A6.

Is there anyway I can have the formula do that?

Sorry if that was way too long,
Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but generally these types of thing are simpler in a VBA macro instead of trying to build a formula in a cell.

Comment: Basically i want the hyperlink to jump me to the cell next to a certain value even if i sort it, rather than to A1, A2, or A3.

Comment: do you know of a format to put it into a macro?

Answer (score 0):

For example if you're on sheet1 and want to go to the row in sheet2 where there's a specific value in ColA:

=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A" & MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),"go")

Comment: Thanks for your help! i did figure out this is what i need =IF(A4="S",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#"&E4,"!A1"),"☠"),IF(A4="A",HYPERLINK(("#Encounter!B"&B4),"⚔")))